# Adjusting the width of header not taking place

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having a *header.php* file which is used for the header of the every web page in web site.I include this on every page of website.But this index covers the whole page. How can I adjust the height of the header so that it appears only on top side of the webpage. I want height of this header to be 150px and width to be full page.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 2px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: right;
  background: #E3CAA1;
}

ul {
  font-size:15px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  z-index:100;


}

ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  background: #6ec749;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;

}

ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}

ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 140px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

ul>li:last-child ul {
  right: 4px;
  left: auto;
}

ul li ul li {

  background: #555;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}

ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #666;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
li{
font-size:20px; 

}
a {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 2px 1px 0;
  color:white;

a:link {
  color: red;
}

a:visited {
  color: purple;
}

a:focus, a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<a href="dashboard.php">
    <img src="/assets/images/logo2.png" width=8% align=left style="display:block;">
 </a>
    <h4 style="color:blue;text-shadow: 4px 4px 8px #c2d4ff; padding-right:10px;font-weight: bold;">STATIONERY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM </h4>
    
    <ul >
      <li ><a href="myprofile.php"style="color:black;" >My Profile</a></li>
     
       <li>
             Stationery Details 
             <ul>
          <li><a href="apply-stationery.php">Apply Stationery</a></li>
         <li><a href="stationeryhistory.php">Stationery History</a></li>
                               
        </ul>
      </li>
       
      <li ><a href="emp-changepassword.php" style="color:black;"  >Change Password</a></li>
      <li ><a href="logout.php" style="color:black;"  >Log-Out</a></li>
     
    </ul>
```

Main page where  this header is included

```
</head>
    <body>
 
        <?php include('includes/header.php');?>    
      <!-- <?php include('includes/sidebar.php');?>-->
            <main class="mn-inner">
                <div class="row" style=" display: block;  margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto;">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <h4 style="text-align:center;">Change Pasword</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s6 m6 " style="position:fixed;margin: auto;  background-color: #f3f3f3;top: 40%; left: 25%;" >
                        <div class="card" >
                            <div class="card-content">
                              
                                <div class="row">
                                    <form class="col s12" name="chngpwd" method="post">
                                          <?php if($error){?><div class="errorWrap"><strong>ERROR</strong>:<?php echo htmlentities($error); ?> </div><?php } 
                else if($msg){?><div class="succWrap"><strong>SUCCESS</strong>:<?php echo htmlentities($msg); ?> </div><?php }?>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="password" type="password"  class="validate" autocomplete="off" name="password"  required>
                                                <label for="password">Current Password</label>
                                            </div>

  <div class="input-field col s12">
 <input id="password" type="password" name="newpassword" class="validate" autocomplete="off" required>
                                                <label for="password">New Password</label>
                                            </div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="password" type="password" name="confirmpassword" class="validate" autocomplete="off" required>
 <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>
</div>


<div class="input-field col s12">
<button type="submit" name="change" class="waves-effect waves-light btn indigo m-b-xs" onclick="return valid();">Change</button>

</div>




                                        </div>
                                       
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     
             
                   
                    </div>
                
                </div>
            </main>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <?php include('includes/footer.php');?>
        <div>
        <!-- Javascripts -->
        <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/plugins/materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/plugins/material-preloader/js/materialPreloader.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockui.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/alpha.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/pages/form_elements.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I would start with adding a container-div that embraces your header mark-up, then style it accordingly.. Just look for sticky header with BS on SO - There'r literally millions of examples here..

Comment: @iLuvLogix i tried that to but still it is covering full page.Can you give that code by making one block for body and one for footer

Comment: have you tried max-height?

Comment: @iLuvLogix  i tried height

Comment: i tried it  in a div <div style="max-height: 50px;">

Comment: in your css your `a` tag is not closed correctly

Comment: Can you share the code of the parent container where the header is placed in?

Comment: @iLuvLogix I have updated the main code

Comment: @MaxiGui can u tell me where is that mistake please

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code under I added some html to structure it as `header` & `nav`.

This answer is based on what I understood but an image of what you expect would help.

In HTML structure, you should put header into `header` container. Generaly this header has `display:flex` that help to make the structure more flexible.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 2px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: right;
  background: #E3CAA1;
  margin: 0; /********* ADDED TO clear auto margin add by snippet *****/
}

header{ /**************** ADDED ***********/
  display:flex;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: -2px;
  margin-right: -2px;
  padding-right: 8%; /*** Make sure that the nav is correctly position in centered ***/
}

nav{ /**************** ADDED ***********/
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
  font-size:15px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  z-index:100;


}

ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  background: #6ec749;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;

}

ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}

ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 140px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

ul>li:last-child ul {
  right: 4px;
  left: auto;
}

ul li ul li {

  background: #555;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}

ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #666;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
li{
font-size:20px; 

}
a {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 2px 1px 0;
  color:white;
}

a:link {
  color: red;
}

a:visited {
  color: purple;
}

a:focus, a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  color: purple;
}

.nav-logo{ /**************** ADDED ***********/
  width:8%;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<header> <!-- ADDED -->
  <a class="nav-logo" href="dashboard.php"> <!-- ADDED class nav-logo -->
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/07a/beach-soft-light-1379401.jpg" width=100% align=left style="display:block;"><!-- MODIFIED width:8% to 100% -->
  </a>
  <nav> <!-- ADDED -->
    <h4 style="color:blue;text-shadow: 4px 4px 8px #c2d4ff; padding-right:10px;font-weight: bold;">STATIONERY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM </h4>
    
    <ul >
      <li ><a href="myprofile.php"style="color:black;" >My Profile</li>
     
       <li>
             Stationery Details 
             <ul>
          <li><a href="apply-stationery.php">Apply Stationery</a></li>
         <li><a href="stationeryhistory.php">Stationery History</a></li>
                               
        </ul>
      </li>
       
      <li ><a href="emp-changepassword.php" style="color:black;"  >Change Password</a></li>
      <li ><a href="logout.php" style="color:black;"  >Log-Out</a></li>
     
    </ul>
  </nav> <!-- ADDED -->
</header> <!-- ADDED -->
```

Comment: _"Can you give that code.."_ - a classic here on SO.. ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix what do you mean ?

Comment: -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320536/what-is-the-best-triage-response-for-give-me-teh-codez-questions & https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13231/what-does-do-you-haz-teh-codez-mean Look at the second comment to the question above - you will get the point..

Comment: @iLuvLogix I did not read those comments actualy... But in this case that it is a bit different than a pure "gimme the code" because the user provide code. The "gimme code" is more like a user that show a picture and wait for code

Comment: Somehow agree, but there won't be any learning experience that will stick - instead the provided solution is copied and pasted. I think ppl should be lead on the right track, do their homework, rtfm & just try it themselves - this way the gained knowledge sticks.  Nevertheless +1 for the answer from me.. ;)

Comment: Sure, it will depend on him to ask "what does the code do" But I will also provide more explication